# Move objects from unordered associative container

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way in c++0x of moving objects out from unordered associative containers? I need to merge two separate unordered sets and I would like, in case rvalues are involved, to 'recycle' items in the soon-ceased-to-be sets.

Thing is, unordered_set's iterators provide only const references to the stored items. I had thought initially of using const_cast to throw away the const-ness, but upon further reading it seems this results in undefined behavior. Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

Take this simple-minded example:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

void merge_sets(unordered_set<string> &s1, unordered_set<string> &&s2)
{
   // Something like this, which (of course) does not work.
   for (auto it = s2.begin(); it != s2.end(); ++it) {
     s1.insert(std::move(*it));
   }
}

int main()
{
   unordered_set<string> s1, s2;
   // Fill first set:
   s1.insert("hello");
   s1.insert("world");
   // Fill second set.
   s2.insert("foo");
   merge_sets(s1,std::move(s2));
   // After this operation, s2 is empty and s1 contains "hello", "world" and "foo".
}
```

In other words, I would like to be able to move the items from s2 instead of copying them. There should be a way to "extract" items from a set in such a way that the item is copied/moved and then erased from the current set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not merge the two sets by using one of them as the target, rather than merging them into a third, separate set?  This would at least let you avoid copying elements from one of the source sets (presumably you'd choose the larger one).

Or, if the elements are large, you should store them indirectly using smart pointers (e.g. `boost::shared_ptr<>`), in which case it will be easy to copy the pointers from the two sources to the target and never copy an actual object.

Comment: I've updated the original question with an example.

Regarding the shared_ptr<>, it is certainly a valid solution but in my case the objects are lightweight - although they still require heap memory allocation. I would like to avoid the extra allocations when I could move the objects.

Comment: The sort of thing you are looking for exists for `std::list<>` (it's called `splice`), but not for other container types.  If you want to avoid the extra allocations for the smart pointers themselves, you can use Boost Intrusive to eliminate this overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer for "splice". I'll look again at Boost.intrusive, but in any case at this point I'm considering writing my own minimal implementation of unordered_set. Cheers!

Comment: @blue: Is that really worth the effort? Have you measured this and found it to be the worse performing part of your code?

Comment: @GMan: no I haven't yet, and you are certainly right about that. I suppose the wise path here is to go with unordered_set, profile, and then maybe re-implement.

It just irks me a bit that it seems there is no way of using move semantics in such a case.

Answer (score 6):

There is no such functionality in the current spec.  But you are not alone in requesting it.  It is possible that we may get this functionality in the future, but only if people such as yourself make lots of noise about needing it.

[LWG issue 839](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#839) has a comment marked "[ 2009-09-19 Howard adds: ]" which describes an API for splicing nodes from one node-based container to another.  Using your code it would look like:

```
void merge_sets(unordered_set<string> &s1, unordered_set<string> &&s2)
{
   // Something like this, which (of course) does not work.
   for (auto it = s2.begin(); it != s2.end();) {
     s1.insert(s2.remove(it++));
   }
}
```

This would not involve **any** memory allocation or deallocation.  It would not even require moving or copying from your element.  It literally passes a node from one `unordered_set<string>` to another.

Tell your National Body representative that you need this functionality.  Tell comp.std.c++ you need this functionality.  If you're not sure this API meets your needs, ask me, either privately or here, and I will clarify if I can.

Comment: Good to hear from someone so involved in the process, but I think this ought to be done more generically than only "splicing" into another container.  There ought to be a way to obtain an xvalue when removing a single element from any of the containers.  Maybe a `remove_swap` function for containers that don't allow modification of elements while contained.

Comment: There is a bullet "Change the value in a `std::set` without the cost of node reallocation".  Is this the functionality you want?

Comment: @Howard: I'm pretty sure that would be useful in its own right, but this question appears to be about being able to claim resources from an item that is being destroyed by virtue of being erased from the set.  I think that would make it an xvalue.  Seems like it would be useful to have a `swap_element` that removes the key from the hashed lookup structure, swaps the value, and re-inserts the key, as well as `remove_swap` that removes the key, swaps the value, and then destroys the element.  In either case, the resources owned by the element would be handed over to an external object.

Comment: `auto p = m.remove(i);
Key new_key = ...;
swap(new_key, p->first);
m.insert(std::move(p));`
For your latter example, just don't do the insertion.  `p`'s destructor will clean up the resources.

Comment: @Howard: I assume you meant `erase`, as there is no `unordered_set::remove`.  But the iterator returned by `erase` has `const` members and can't be used with `swap`.  `[unord.set]` states "The `iterator` and `const_iterator` types are both const iterator types."

Comment: @Ben:  I'm discussing a proposal sketched out in the 2009-09-19 comment of LWG 839 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#839).  Please read it.

Comment: @Howard: Yes, that looks like the perfect resolution to this.  "API for splicing" is no longer a good summary since your proposal is much more flexible.  Too bad this didn't make it into C++0x.

Comment: Yes, this proposal is well hidden.  That's why I'm trying to shine a bright light on it.  With your help, and the help of others (shining a bright light on it), it might make it into TR2 and/or C++1x.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change an element in a Set (ordered or not) because this breaks the uniqueness guarantee.

Comment: That's not quite right.  You can't change an element in a set in a way that would change its ordering within the set (as defined by the comparator used by that set).  It's possible for example to have `mutable` fields in the value_type of your set and it is then OK to modify those fields on elements within a set so long as those fields aren't used in the comparison function.

Comment: Moving from the member is highly likely to change the ordering, unless you are extremely careful in defining the element type.