# C++ converting map<int, set<int> > into map<int, vector<int>>

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, set, move

I have to convert an std::map like this:

```
std::map<int, std::set<int> > t_contents;
```

in a map like this:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int> > seq;
```

I am doing the conversion this way:

```
std::map<int, std::set<int> >::const_iterator it;
for(it = t_contents.begin(); it != t_contents.end(); ++it)
{    
    std::move((*it).second.begin(), (*it).second.end(), 
        std::back_inserter(seq[(*it).first])
    );   
}
```

Consider that the map contains up to 1 million elements and each set can contain also up ti 10 thousand. This is the best solution I have found in terms of space wasting and time; is there any better way to do this work?

Comment: By the way, `(*it).` is the same as `it->`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance will be better (amortised constant per insertion) if you use hinted insertion:

```
std::map<int, std::set<int> >::const_iterator it;
for (it = t_contents.begin(); it != t_contents.end(); ++it) {
    std::vector<int> &vec = seq.insert(seq.end(),
        std::make_pair(it->first, std::vector<int>()))->second;
    vec.reserve(it->second.size());
    vec.assign(it->second.begin(), it->second.end());
}
```

Use `reserve` to prevent reallocations, and use `vector::assign` with iterator arguments; it's more readable (if no more efficient) than `back_inserter`.

An alternative is to emplace the vector directly into the map, still using a hint:

```
std::map<int, std::set<int> >::const_iterator it;
for (it = t_contents.begin(); it != t_contents.end(); ++it) {
    seq.emplace_hint(seq.end(), it->first,
        std::vector<int>(it->second.begin(), it->second.end());
}
```

Note that there's no need to `move` the set elements; as they're primitives a move is the same as a copy.

This may be faster or slower, depending e.g. on whether `insert` checks the distance between iterator arguments (it's O(n) on the set size in any case).

Comment: I think you've to `reserve` only when the elements are going to be `push_back`'d one by one, when using `assign` you could safely omit it. It is similar to calling the ctor with begin and end iterators.

Comment: I initially thought the reserve was unnecessary, but actually `reserve(s.size())` is faster than letting `assign` count the elements by traversing the range with `std::distance`. The assign could use `std::make_move_iterator(it->second.begin())` and similarly for `end` so the elements are moved, as in the original question

Comment: @legends2k the constructor is specifically documented as checking the distance between the iterators; `assign` (and `insert`) isn't, although it's highly likely that an implementation would make the check in the same situations.

Comment: @JonathanWakely why bother moving `int`s?

Comment: Ah, except moving still wouldn't do anything, as `set::iterator` is not a mutable iterator

Comment: @JonathanWakely quite.  I suspect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181003/move-objects-from-unordered-associative-container may be relevant here.

Comment: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) says (too lazy to consult the standard, though) that the insertion should happen **before** the hint instead of **after** in C++11, in which case you should rather always pass `seq.end()` as hint (at least in C++11).

Comment: @ChristianRau, the insertion happens wherever dictated by the container's comparison functor, not where the hint says! The hint affects how quickly that position is found, it doesn't affect where the element gets inserted

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yes, of course I know this (even if a failed at your particular answer ;)). I was referring to the fact that the usage of the previous insertion iterator as hint resulted in logarithmic insertion rather than constant (which is what hint is for). Therefore the *"should"* in my comment. Never did I say that insertion happens at the hint in any way (and I wonder how this could be extracted from my comments).

Answer (score 3):

Another option is:

```
std::transform(t_contents.begin(), t_contents.end(), std::inserter(seq.begin()),
  [](const std::pair<const int, std::set<int>>& s) {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(s.second.size());
    v.assign(s.second.begin(), s.second.end());
    return std::make_pair(s.first, std::move(v));
  }
);
```

Moving `int`s is pointless, and `std::set` iterators are const anyway so you can't move out of a set.

Like ecatmur's answer this benefits from inserting with a hint, because each assignment to the `insert_iterator` does an `insert` with the previous insertion point as the hint, which is a huge performance benefit because the input range is already sorted with the same ordering, so each successive insertion is adjacent to the last.

Comment: Unfortunately, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) says (too lazy to consult the standard, though) that the insertion should happen **before** the hint instead of **after** in C++11, so using `seq.begin()` won't be a good idea. But unfortunately `seq.end()` won't work if the `insert_iterator` always increases the hint after each insertion.

Comment: @ChristianRau, when I call `seq.begin()` the map is empty, so `seq.begin()==seq.end()` so what other value do you suggest using?! `insert_iterator` doesn't increase the hint, it gets set to the location of the insertion, stop being lazy and check the standard ;) Also, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1780.html and http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-defects.html#233

Comment: Yeah, right. 24.5.2.6.2 [insert.iter.op=] says *"Effects:
`iter = container->insert(iter, value); ++iter;`"*. In fact I missed the `iter =` part and thought it just increases the initial hint, which would have resulted in logarithmic insertion for `seq.begin()` and failed for `seq.end()`. In fact cppreference was exactly conforming to the standard but I just failed to read properly (thus I was rather stupid than lazy ;)).